# How to copy a selection from Direct2DCanvas to clipboard?

Tags: delphi, clipboard, direct2d

I made a small program to draw geometry figures on a D2DBox (with Direct2DCanvas and RenderTarget) and I need to be able to copy a rectangle from it to the clipboard. Tried this, but I'm stuck with the source handle parameter:

```
bm := TBitmap.Create;
try
  bm.SetSize(maxx-minx, maxy-miny);
  BitBlt(bm.Canvas.Handle, minx, miny, maxx, maxy, ??? , 0, 0, SRCCOPY);
  Clipboard.Assign(bm);
finally
  bm.Free;
end;
```

Any idea where to get a handle from? Or the whole thing is done a different way? Thanx!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`BitBlt()` requires a GDI `HDC` to copy from, but `TDirect2DCanvas` does not have an `HDC` of its own, and it cannot *directly* render to an off-screen `HDC`/`TCanvas`, such as `TBitmap.Canvas`, per its [documentation](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/en/Vcl.Direct2D.TDirect2DCanvas.Create):

> TDirect2DCanvas will only work for **on-screen device contexts**. You cannot use the TDirect2DCanvas to draw on a printer device context, for example.

And you can't associate a custom `RenderTarget` (such as one created with [`ID2D1Factory.CreateDCRenderTarget()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/d2d1/nf-d2d1-id2d1factory-createdcrendertarget) and [`ID2D1DCRenderTarget.BindDC()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/d2d1/nf-d2d1-id2d1dcrendertarget-binddc)) since the [TDirect2DCanvas.RenderTarget](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/en/Vcl.Direct2D.TDirect2DCanvas.RenderTarget) property is read-only.

So, you will likely have to go a long way to get what you want.  Based on code I found in [Direct2d Desktop printing C++](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/azure/en-US/a60bb411-1f79-4115-adfe-0295ae91e65f/direct2d-desktop-printing-c?forum=windowssdk), which demonstrates copying an arbitrary `ID2D1RenderTarget` to an arbitrary `HDC`, you can try the following:

- Create a Direct2D `ID2D1Bitmap` that is bound to the canvas's current `RenderTarget` using one of the target's [`CreateBitmap()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/d2d1/nf-d2d1-id2d1rendertarget-createbitmap(d2d1_size_u_constvoid_uint32_constd2d1_bitmap_properties_id2d1bitmap)) methods.
- Copy pixels from the canvas into the bitmap using the bitmap's [`CopyFromRenderTarget()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/d2d1/nf-d2d1-id2d1bitmap-copyfromrendertarget) method.
- Create an [`IWICBitmap`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/wincodec/nn-wincodec-iwicbitmap) (you can probably use the VCL's [`TWICImage`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/en/Vcl.Graphics.TWICImage) for this) and render the Direct2D bitmap to it using one of the [`ID2D1Factory.CreateWicBitmapRenderTarget()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/d2d1/nf-d2d1-id2d1factory-createwicbitmaprendertarget(iwicbitmap_constd2d1_render_target_properties_id2d1rendertarget)) methods with one of the [`ID2D1RenderTarget.DrawBitmap()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/d2d1/nf-d2d1-id2d1rendertarget-drawbitmap(id2d1bitmap_constd2d1_rect_f_float_d2d1_bitmap_interpolation_mode_constd2d1_rect_f)) methods.
- Create a GDI `DIB` bitmap and render the `IWICBitmap` to it using the WIC bitmap's [`CopyPixels()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/wincodec/nf-wincodec-iwicbitmapsource-copypixels) method.
- Finally, you use the `DIB` however you needed, such as select/copy it to your final `HDC`, or you can simply place its contents directly on the clipboard using the `CF_DIB` format.

Here is the code (sorry, it is in C++, I'm not going to translate it to Delphi):

> ```cpp
> void Direct2DRender::RenderToDC(HDC hDC, UINT uiWidth, UINT uiHeight)
> {
>   HRESULT hr = S_OK;
>
>   IWICImagingFactory *pImageFactory = WICImagingFactory::GetInstance().GetFactory();
>
>   CComPtr<IWICBitmap> wicBitmap;
>   hr = pImageFactory->CreateBitmap( uiWidth, uiHeight, GUID_WICPixelFormat32bppBGR, WICBitmapCacheOnLoad, &wicBitmap);
>
>   D2D1_SIZE_U bitmapPixelSize = D2D1::SizeU( uiWidth, uiHeight);
>
>   float dpiX, dpiY;
>   m_pRenderTarget->GetDpi( &dpiX, &dpiY);
>
>   CComPtr<ID2D1Bitmap> d2dBitmap;
>   hr = m_pRenderTarget->CreateBitmap( bitmapPixelSize, D2D1::BitmapProperties(
>     D2D1::PixelFormat(DXGI_FORMAT_B8G8R8A8_UNORM, D2D1_ALPHA_MODE_IGNORE),
>     dpiX, dpiY), &d2dBitmap );
>
>   D2D1_POINT_2U dest = D2D1::Point2U(0,0);
>   D2D1_RECT_U src = D2D1::RectU(0, 0, uiWidth, uiHeight);
>
>   hr = d2dBitmap->CopyFromRenderTarget(&dest, m_pRenderTarget, &src);
>
>   D2D1_RENDER_TARGET_PROPERTIES rtProps = D2D1::RenderTargetProperties();
>     rtProps.pixelFormat = D2D1::PixelFormat(DXGI_FORMAT_B8G8R8A8_UNORM, D2D1_ALPHA_MODE_IGNORE);
>     rtProps.type = D2D1_RENDER_TARGET_TYPE_DEFAULT;
>     rtProps.usage = D2D1_RENDER_TARGET_USAGE_NONE;
>
>   CComPtr<ID2D1RenderTarget> wicRenderTarget;
>   hr = m_pDirect2dFactory->CreateWicBitmapRenderTarget( wicBitmap, rtProps, &wicRenderTarget);
>
>   wicRenderTarget->BeginDraw();
>   wicRenderTarget->DrawBitmap(d2dBitmap);
>   hr = wicRenderTarget->EndDraw();
>
>   // Render the image to a GDI device context
>   HBITMAP hDIBBitmap = NULL;
>   try
>   {
>     // Get a DC for the full screen
>     HDC hdcScreen = GetDC(NULL);
>     if (!hdcScreen)
>       throw 1;
>
>     BITMAPINFO bminfo;
>     ZeroMemory(&bminfo, sizeof(bminfo));
>     bminfo.bmiHeader.biSize         = sizeof(BITMAPINFOHEADER);
>     bminfo.bmiHeader.biWidth        = uiWidth;
>     bminfo.bmiHeader.biHeight       = -(LONG)uiHeight;
>     bminfo.bmiHeader.biPlanes       = 1;
>     bminfo.bmiHeader.biBitCount     = 32;
>     bminfo.bmiHeader.biCompression  = BI_RGB;     
>
>     void* pvImageBits = nullptr;  // Freed with DeleteObject(hDIBBitmap)
>     hDIBBitmap = CreateDIBSection(hdcScreen, &bminfo, DIB_RGB_COLORS, &pvImageBits, NULL, 0);
>     if (!hDIBBitmap)
>       throw 2;
>
>     ReleaseDC(NULL, hdcScreen);
>
>     // Calculate the number of bytes in 1 scanline
>     UINT nStride = DIB_WIDTHBYTES(uiWidth * 32);
>     // Calculate the total size of the image
>     UINT nImage = nStride * uiHeight;
>     // Copy the pixels to the DIB section
>     hr = wicBitmap->CopyPixels(nullptr, nStride, nImage, reinterpret_cast<BYTE*>(pvImageBits));
>
>     // Copy the bitmap to the target device context
>     ::SetDIBitsToDevice(hDC, 0, 0, uiWidth, uiHeight, 0, 0, 0, uiHeight, pvImageBits, &bminfo, DIB_RGB_COLORS);
>
>     DeleteObject(hDIBBitmap);
>   }
>   catch (...)
>   {
>     if (hDIBBitmap)
>       DeleteObject(hDIBBitmap);
>     // Rethrow the exception, so the client code can handle it
>     throw;
>   }
> }
> ```

In that same discussion, another alternative is described:

> - Create a DIB section, and select it into a DC
> - Create a DC render target
> - Bind the render target to the DC that corresponds to the DIB section
> - Draw using Direct2D. After calling EndDraw the DIB contains what was rendered.
> - The final step is to draw the dib where you need it.

So, try moving your drawing code to its own function that takes an `ID2D1RenderTarget` as input and draws on it as needed.  Then, you can create an `HDC`-based `RenderTarget` when you want to place a bitmap on the clipboard, and use `TDirect2DCanvas.RenderTarget` when you want to draw on your `D2DBox`.

Comment: I was afraid it will not be as simple as I was thinking, so I just made a printscreen, copied the rectangle I need and put it in the clipboard. Just to mention that for Direct2D TForm.getFormImage does not work.